# android app will receive the BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE broadcast when phone is away from the paired device at a distance

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I used "createBond" method to pair my phone and my device with BLE.it succeed.but I took my phone away from the device at a distance, about 10 meters.My app received the broadcast: BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED, and the device status is became BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE. Is it normal or something wrong? 
after my app receive the broadcast I will unpaired the device.because I think the device is unpaired manually by user from setting activity.

Answer (score 1):

10 meters is a normal range for a BLE device.  You got too far from it so you couldn't maintain a connection.  This is normal.  With some devices the distance will be even shorter (perhaps 5m).

Comment: But I am confused that when the user paired the ble device used system setting activity. when the ble device is out of distance, it does not unpaired the device.

Comment: Pairing and connection are two different things. The BLE might not be connected but, it can be shown in the paired list of Android once its paired.

Answer (score 0):

`BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE` broadcast when phone is away from the paired device at a distance is not normal I guess.

Yes, the disconnection from the paired device when you're out of the bluetooth range is normal, but, as I said earlier in the comment, pairing and connectivity are two different things. The BLE might not be connected but, it can be shown in the paired list of Android once its paired.

And another interesting thing what I want to share in this case is, the bluetooth devices which are already paired once with an Android, are somehow remembered in Android device even if you un-pair them. I had this tested for some of my personal projects.

Comment: as I know, when  the phone is away from the paired device. It just broke the connection relationship not pair relationship. but I receive the  ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED broadcast and the bond status of the device became BOND_NONE. How to explain the phenomenon ？

Comment: there is a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034237/android-bluetooth-paired-devices-list : I am guessing that some devices will consider it as a temporary pairing and will not keep the device in the paired list after the connection is disconnected.  --- I don't know this is right or not

Comment: As far as I know about the Android bluetooth I didn't find anything like temporary paired list. So I don't have any idea about it dear. And about the answer you linked in your comment. This doesn't lead to an idea of temporary pairing either.